# Changes to Pointers not made permanent

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, linked-list

```
struct Limit
    {
    float Price;
    int size;
    int Volume;
    struct Limit *Parent;
    struct Limit *ltChild;
    struct Limit *rtChild;
    struct list_head* Order;
    };
typedef struct Limit Limit;

struct Order
    {   
     double idNum;
     bool BuySell;
         int shares;
     float limitPrice;
         char* entryTime;
     char* eventTime;
         struct list_head ord_Queue;
    };
typedef struct Order Order;
void AddOrder(Order* newOrder,Limit* Limit,HXmap* OrderMap)
 {
    list_add_tail(&newOrder->ord_Queue,Limit->Order);
    HXmap_add(OrderMap,&newOrder->idNum,newOrder);
    Limit->size++;
    Limit->Volume +=newOrder->shares;

 }
void ModifyOrder(float oLimit, int oShares,float nLimit,int nShares,HXmap* LimitMap,HXmap* OrderMap, oBook* OrderBook)
{
    Limit* ParentLimit = (Limit*)HXmap_get(LimitMap,&oLimit);
    if(ParentLimit==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERRONEOUS ORDER\n");
        return;
    }
    struct list_head *pos;
    pos = ParentLimit->Order->next;
    Order* Ord= NULL;
        while(pos!=ParentLimit->Order)   
    {
        Ord = list_entry((pos),Order,ord_Queue);
        if(Ord->shares==oShares)         
        break;                               //found the order
        else pos = pos->next;
    }
    if(pos==ParentLimit->Order && Ord->shares!=oShares)
        {
            printf("ORDER NOT FOUND\n");
            return;
        }
    if(oLimit==nLimit)
    {
        ParentLimit->Volume  = (ParentLimit->Volume + nShares)-oShares;
        Ord->shares = nShares;
    }
    else
    {
               //delete from list
        Ord->ord_Queue.next->prev = Ord->ord_Queue.prev;
        Ord->ord_Queue.prev->next = Ord->ord_Queue.next;
          ParentLimit->size--;
        HXmap_del(OrderMap,&Ord->idNum);
        if(ParentLimit->Volume==Ord->shares)
        {
            if(Ord->BuySell==1)
            OrderBook->buyTree = RemoveLimit(OrderBook->buyTree,ParentLimit,LimitMap);
            else
            OrderBook->sellTree = RemoveLimit(OrderBook->sellTree,ParentLimit,LimitMap);
        }
        else
        ParentLimit->Volume-=Ord->shares;
            Ord->limitPrice = nLimit;
            Ord->shares = nShares;
            INIT_LIST_HEAD(&Ord->ord_Queue);            
            ParentLimit = HXmap_get(LimitMap,&nLimit);
            if(ParentLimit==NULL)
            {
                ParentLimit = Limit_init(nLimit);
                if(Ord->BuySell==1)
                OrderBook->buyTree= AddLimit(OrderBook->buyTree,ParentLimit,LimitMap);
                else
                OrderBook->sellTree = AddLimit(OrderBook->sellTree,ParentLimit,LimitMap);
            }
            AddOrder(Ord,ParentLimit,OrderMap);
    }

}
```

Okay, its a longish code, but much of it is purely intuitive. [It uses list.h Kernel Linked List and its associate functions.More info about KLL can be found [here](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) ]The idea, is when a message to modify a preexisting order at a particular price(its a financial code) arrives, it removes the order from the previous "queue" of its old Price (ParentLimit in `ModifyOrder()` ) finds the address of new limit price structure by querying the map, if it doesnt exist, creates a new limit and add the order else it simply adds it.

Now, I enter same message of modifying orders in a particular limit price.
Configuration before passing the messages:

`Limit Price : 181.25, two orders of 250 shares each.`

When I pass, the first modify message, to modify the first order of 250 shares from 181.25 to 181.35(no previous limit exists so it will create a new limit and add it to the tree), the control eventually flows to `AddOrder()` hence, adding the orders. Definition of `AddOrder()` function is attached, though its very simplistic and calls `list_add_tail()` to add it to list.

After the first modification(and addition of order), the DDD gives me this situation:

```
Address of ParentLimit: 0x804f1d0
Address of            ->Order: 804f710
Contents of                   ->next: 804dec4
Contents of                   ->prev: 804dec4

Address of Order->ord_Queue (just inserted): 0x804dec4
Contents  of Order->ord_Queue->prev: 0x804f710
Contents of Order->ord_Queue->next: 0x804f710
```

This shows the addition of the order to the queue has taken place successfully.

When I pass the second message to modify another order at the same old price (181.25 to 181.35) and query the map to find me the address of the new Limit Price,

The situation is:

```
Address of ParentLimit: 0x804f1d0
    Address of            ->Order: 804f710
    Contents of                   ->next: 804f710
    Contents of                   ->prev: 804f710
```

Which means, that somehow the change made was not made permanent. I dont know why this is happeneing.

Comment: I think you really have to cook down your code, you can't expect somebody else to do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I agree... Infact I was a bit reluctant to post it at the first place, but then spending the last 48 hours behind it, kind of made me amenable to any help

Comment: you have to use pointers to pointers (`**`) to be able to change the pointer outside the function

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior you expect, given your description of where you are querying.  These lines will remove the order from your linked list before your query the map to get a ParentLimit for the new price:

```
    Ord->ord_Queue.next->prev = Ord->ord_Queue.prev;
    Ord->ord_Queue.prev->next = Ord->ord_Queue.next;
```

---

To clarify:  `Limit.Order` is a pointer.  It will follow your list head even when you move it to other lists.  Thus, deleting from from your old list ends up following a pointer to your new list if you only have one order.  You will either need to make it an embedded struct or keep a dummy head that is empty for both new and old lists.

Comment: First of all, Seth accept my apologies for such a late comeback. I have a few questions, because I dont think I am getting you well: Say there is only one order for a particular `ParentLimit`. So, `ParentLimit->Order->prev = the one and only order`, and similarly, `ParentLimit->Order->next = the one and only order`, same thing with the order as well. Its a doubly circular linked list. Now when the LHS of the first statement(you highlighted) can also be shown as `(ParentLimit->Order)->prev = ParentLimit->Order` and similarly the others (thats what I intended), yielding a list pointing to itself

Comment: So my question is how the pointer is following the order to the new list.

Comment: What I mean is that `Limit.order` never changes.  Even though you change an order's limit price, the `Limit.order` pointer remains pointing at the same order with the new price.  Thus, when you modify another order at the same initial price, it pulls the linked list from your new order and deletes that order from the list.  It can help to think of the limiting cases.  How would you detect an empty order list in the Limit structure?  Given the pointer structure you have, there are two options: Either `Limit.order` is NULL or it points to an empty/dummy structure.

Comment: Defining the empty case first can help prevent the pointer from wandering like this.